# Minimum no of characters to be deleted from both the strings to make it anagram

Tags: c++, string

I have to find the minimum no of characters to be deleted in order to make the two strings anagram,but my code is not giving the exact value which is required:

My code:

```
int main() {

    int arr[26]={0};
    int i,cont=0;
    char a[10000];
    char b[10000];
    cin>>a;
    cin>>b;
   int l1=strlen(a);
   int l2=strlen(b);
    for(i=0;i<l1;i++)
        arr[a[i]-'a']+=1;
    for(i=0;i<l2;i++)
        arr[b[i]-'a']-=1;
    for(i=0;i<26;i++)
    {
        if(arr[i]!=0)
        {

            cont=cont+abs(arr[i]);
        }
    }
    cout<<cont;
    return 0;
}
```

Explanation to my code:

I have created an array of `26` memory locations in it,initializing all to `0`.
Then I am generating the location `arr[i]` contains a character and if we subtract it by `'a'`,it will give the exact location:like if `arr[i]='a'` the `'a'-a'=0`,for the first string I am adding 1 to it and for the other string I am subtracting 1 to it as a result I am getting those locations or alphabets that are not matched ,I am counting them up in order to get the answer.

But for this testcase:

```
fcrxzwscanmligyxyvym     // First string

jxwtrhvujlmrpdoqbisbwhmgpmeoke     //Second string
```

The output :

```
30
```

Not getting the correct output

Comment: Minimum no of deletion that will make the strings to become anagram of each other

Comment: Can you explain to us what your code is doing, please?

Comment: show us for which input it gives wrong output and also give us the output you obtained and the expected output

Comment: edit your question and add this there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `for` loops scan first 26 characters of the input strings, despite the fact those strings may be shorter than or longer than 26 characters...

Comment: Thanx for the help ,but by mistake I typed 26 there,I am scanning till the length of the string

Answer (score 0):

In javascript you can do like this.

```
var input ="accfgilmmnrsvwxxyyyz\nbddeeghhijjklmmmooppqrrstuvwwx";

var str1, str2, arr =[], l1, l2, t1, t2;

arr = input.trim().split('\n');
str1 = arr[0].toLowerCase();
str2 = arr[1].toLowerCase();
if(str1.length>str2.length){
  temp = str1;
  str1 = str2;
  str2 = temp;
}
l1 = str1.length;
l2 = str2.length;
var  n=0;

for(var i=0; i<l1; i++){
  if(str2.indexOf(str1[i]) != -1){
    var j = str2.indexOf(str1[i]);
    str2 = str2.slice(0, j) + str2.slice(j+1);
    n++;
  }
}

console.log(l1+l2-n-n);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
int numberNeeded(String first, String second) {
  int[] map=new int[255];
    int len1=first.length();
    int len2=second.length();

    for(int i=0;i<len1;i++)
        map[(int)first.charAt(i)]++;
    for(int i=0;i<len2;i++)
        map[(int)second.charAt(i)]--;
    int count=0;
    for(int i=0;i<255;i++)
        {
        count=count+Math.abs(map[i]);
    }
    return count;
}
```

Find here what you are doing wrong

Comment: A nice explanation along with the code would add value to your answer

Comment: There are 256 type of character are there in ascii so you need to take 256 size map to count number of time a particular character are visible.